# When exit_cb is called when use job_start to execute a command? Is it called when command is finished?

Tags: vim

```
function! Add_CsTag()
    echo 'call add tags' 
    if filereadable("cscope.out") 
        cs add . 
        echo 'cs add' 
    endif
endfunction
function! Do_CsTag() 
    call job_start('cscope -Rbk', {"exit_cb": Add_CsTag()}) 
endfunction
```

These are my codes. I want to start a background task to generate cscope database. But it fails. Because cscope.out is not readable when function is called. It looks like the exit_cb is called before the cscope -Rbk command finished. The cscope.out is generated successfully. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Also tried close_cb, it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1):

The `exit_cb` option is supposed to be a function name, not a function call:

```
"exit_cb": "Add_CsTag"
```

You can also use this form:

```
"exit_cb": function("Add_CsTag")
```

See `:help function()`.